# C++ Passing Multi-Dimensional Array into Function

Tags: c++, parameters

So I already saw this [C++ Passing multi-dimensional arrays into functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26264726/c-passing-multi-dimensional-arrays-into-functions?lq=1) but it says to put the value of the Column in for the parameter.

For a 3x3 array does that mean saying

```
void printGrid (char ticTacToeBoard[][2])
```

or

```
void printGrid (char ticTacToeBoard[][3])
```

When trying to pass it through?

Comment: possible duplicate of [passing 2D array to function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767166/passing-2d-array-to-function)

Answer (score 0):

```
void printGrid (char ticTacToeBoard[][3])
```

Answer (score 0):

With

```
char board[3][3];
```

the prototype would be

```
void printGrid(const char (&ticTacToeBoard)[3][3]);
```

and call it that way:

```
printGrid(board);
```

Comment: Can you explain exactly why you would use your prototype as opposed to Ken's? Not to say anything is wrong with his, but that is the way all the stuff I was reading seemed to point. My knowledge on when you use the & is pretty poor and all, so just curious why you'd use the const and the &ticTacToeBoard.

Comment: @Idehart: I set the 2 dimensions of the array whereas `char ticTacToeBoard[][3]` (which is equivalent to `char (*ticTacToeBoard)[3]`) only set one dimension (and so is less typed). And I add `const` as I expected that `printGrid` doesn't change board content.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response, that makes a lot of sense! What's the purpose of using &ticTacToeBoard as opposed to just ticTacToeBoard?

Comment: @Idehart: The syntax to pass array is not intuitive, if you just do `void printGrid(char board[3][3]);`, it will be in fact `void printGrid(char board[][3]);` (and so `void printGrid(char (*board)[3]);`). Using `std::vector` or `std::array` is really more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

void printGrid (char** ticTacToeBoard)

Comment: Select your code, and click on ctrl+K to indent it correctly (or indent manually your code with 4 space to show it as code).

Comment: I think that OP has `char board[3][3];` and not `char* board[3];`.